# Display table content as tree

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a categories table where my application store (Category id, category name, and category parent). I am wondering is there a way (HQL, Java code) where I can display the table content in the following format?

```
- 1  Cat 1 
---- 11 Cat 11
-------- 111 Cat 111
- 2 Cat 2
---- 22 Cat 22

Category_id  |  Name    | category_parent
1            |  cat 1   | 0
11           |  cat 11  | 1
111          |  cat 111 | 11
2            |  cat 2   | 0
22           |  cat 22  | 2
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) would be the natural choice to [view](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692) such data,

[image]

but a tree-table such as [`Outline`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) is a convenient alternative.

[image]